# How do human rights and Christianity relate to each other?

Tags: morality, human-rights

Now it is really getting interesting - this is the third question in a row (after [this one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/are-love-and-hate-in-a-harmonious-balance-within-god) and [this one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2265/how-can-things-considered-bad-when-done-by-humans-become-good-when-god-does-them)). So please make sure you read those two to understand this one in context.

Caleb wrote:

> human rights is another issue! That is another example of something
>   that is not wrong for God but very much wrong for humans. I do believe
>   in human rights (by virtue of being created in God's image AND being
>   his property that man should not dare to trespass and abuse) but that
>   might be the topic for another question in itself.

Continuing:

> However I would still assert that Christianity is not in conflict with
>   undeniable human rights. In fact they are absolute in so far as they
>   are granted by an absolute God.

**My question is:**

How is God allowed to breach these undeniable human rights for example by extensive torturing people?

*Again: Please make sure you read the other questions and especially [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/are-love-and-hate-in-a-harmonious-balance-within-god/2263#2263) and [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2265/how-can-things-considered-bad-when-done-by-humans-become-good-when-god-does-them/2267#2267) answer and the comments to make sure that you understand the context of this question! Thank you!*

Comment: **Needs some work**: Questions that spawn followup questions are usually intriguing, but this question needs to be reworked. You shouldn't have to start with "read this this this and this." If the very *premise* of the question is to follow a pseudo conversation that winds around the site, it's becomes your own private debate. If you have a question, **ask it on it's *own* merits as a completely formed, stand-alone question.** See if you can **start** with the question. Add whatever quotes you need but they should be secondary to the question... not the *focus.*

Comment: @vonjd I'm interested in getting this question re-opened. Besides having an answer cooking, I think there might be more interesting ones lurking out there in Christianity. How would you feel if I do a re-write to try to scope this in a way that it would be a good SE question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a shot at answering this one.  Most of my answer will be taken from my readings of C.S. Lewis.

The short answer is that we are God's creation and He is allowed to do with us as He likes.  In the flood He wiped out all of humanity save for eight people, but since we are His creation this was OK.

Assume that you were an artist and you created a painting.  Now this painting is your creation; it belongs to you.  You may do with it what you choose.  You may display the painting for all to see, you can restrict who is allowed to see it.  You can alter it as you see fit, you can leave it alone, you can even wipe it out and start all over again.  You can turn it over to someone else so that they can do with it as they like.

All these things are acceptable, but no one else may touch your creation, at least not without your permission.  No one else may harm it or destroy it because it is not theirs, it is yours.

The same can be said about God, people, and human rights.  God may do with us as He chooses because we are His.  We as humans cannot do whatever we like to other humans because we do not own them.